# request.patch gives duplicate value found error for a Salesforce API

Tags: force.com, upsert, python

I have referred [this guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_upsert.htm) to make patch request to a salesforce api.

My python code :

```
headers = {"Authorization" : "OAuth %s"%str(accessToken), "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
try:
    response = requests.patch(url, data, headers=headers)
    self.log.info('request.patch response : %s %s'\
                 % (response.text, response.status_code))
except Exception, e:
    self.log.info("Exception %s"%str(e))
```

I am updating a record that already exist in salesforce. But I am getting below error -

```
response.text = [
  {
   "message":"duplicate value found: mypackageprefix__external_field__c duplicates value on record with id: a1T50000005G9jxyz",
   "errorCode":"DUPLICATE_VALUE",
   "fields":[]
  }
]
response.status_code = 400
```

When does this error occur?

Also, as I am only updating the existing records, ideally I should only get `status_code=204` (like the guide says) But I have been getting `status_code=201` sometimes. Why?

Please help me out.

Comment: You'll get an error if the same External ID value exists on multiple records. Have you checked to make sure only one record has the unique value?

Comment: Yes. I have made sure that external id is unique. Also there is no way I should get 201. Because externalId is passed from salesforce to my app. My app / python script then updates the status for a row with that externalId. I don't know why am I getting 201?

Comment: 201 is "created". A new record was made. The record wasn't identified as an existing record, so it was inserted. I'd check for typos, etc. Also, you can run debug logs in Salesforce to try and determine why it happened.

Comment: @HussainTamboli did you resolve this issue? We are receive same error and can't resolve it for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue one reason for that error can be if we have multiple records in our request with same external_field__c. Like

```
[{"external_field__c": '1',name="test"},
 {"external_field__c": '1',"name="test2"}]
```